# rails page preview haml and html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a page like this,have a `select_tag` used to select the engine is `nil` or `haml`,if the selected `nil`, the body_preview value is `$('#mail_body').val()`,direct display the html code. if the selected 'haml', write  `haml` code in the mail_body,and the body_preview value is convert `$(#mail_body.val())` to html ,convert the haml code only use the static methods, not use ruby dynamic value .

```
<%= select_tag "engine", "<option></option><option>haml</option>",
                   :onchange => "$('#body_preview').trigger('load');"%>

<%= text_area_tag 'mail_body', nil,
                   :onchange => "$('#body_preview').trigger('load');" %>

<iframe id="body_preview"  
      onload="$('#engine').val() == 'haml' ? "???????" : $('#mail_body').val()">
</iframe>
```

when the engine is nil

mail_body

```
#content
  .left.column
    %h2 Welcome to our site!
    %p 2
```

body_preview

```
#content .left.column %h2 Welcome to our site! %p 2
```

when the engine is haml
mail_body

```
#content
  .left.column
    %h2 Welcome to our site!
    %p 2
```

i hope the body_preview is

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="left column">
    <h2>Welcome to our site!</h2>
    <p>2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [haml engine](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Engine.html) to process haml.

```
template = File.read('templates/really_cool_template.haml')
haml_engine = Haml::Engine.new(template)
output = haml_engine.render
puts output
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it's really hard to understand what you're saying. I tried to answer the part that I understood - which made it sound like you want to be able to parse haml directly.